# Solve for $\mathbb{Z}$ the equation $ (x^2+y)(y^2+x)=y^2+69 $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all the pairs $(x,y)$  where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $$(x^2+y)(y^2+x)=y^2+69.$$

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: $(x,y)=(1,4)$ is a solution, so we can forget the "if any" part, proving no such pair exists.

Comment: I dont know how to continue.Please give me few hints.

Comment: A few hints: If $x, y\geq 0$, then the left hand side is at least $y^3$, so there are no solutions with $y>4$.  The right hand side is always positive, so both factors on the left must have the same sign.  You can narrow the search for solutions down further by reducing the equation mod $p$ for various $p$.  For example, mod $2$, since $x^2=x$ for all $x$, the left hand simplifies to $(x+y)(y+x)$, then to $(x+y)$, and so we get $x+y=y+1 \pmod 2$, so $x$ must be odd.  If you find all the solutions mod other small primes, use the chinese remainder theorem, and then look at overall size....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Start with showing that 
$$
(x^2+y)(y^2+x)-y^2>69
$$
for all $x,y$ with $|x|,|y|>4$.

Comment: I have proved it. Can you proceed little further?

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty If you have proved the inequality, that means there are only 81 possible combinations to check.  However, from my hint above we know that $x$ must be odd, which cuts the number of cases in half, approximately.  You can reduce the work further by looking for solutions mod 3.